# How Can I Suppress the Tabular Output from PowerShell’s Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

When calling **Get-ChildItem** during my latest test, its default tabular output returns entries for over 10,000 files, and makes the important data scroll off the top of the console.

Not only that, but it literally hurts my eyes to watch the tsunami of unrequested data flying by. I’ve had cataract and retinal surgery, and my eyes just can’t handle that avalanche.

The code:

```
[System.IO.FileInfo[]] $queue = Get-ChildItem -path $clientRoot -recurse -attributes $ATTRIBUTE_FILTER | Where-Object `
      -filterScript {`
         ($_.fullName -notmatch $EXCLUSIONS) -and ($_.lastWriteTime -gt $lastUploadTime) `
      }
```

I tried adding **| Out-Null**, which suppressed the output, but also kept the **$queue** object from being populated.

I’ve been fighting this for two days, without success. Anyone know how to suppress **Get-ChildItem**’s default tabular output?

$PSVersion table output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.5
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.5
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

FYI, this is basically a continuation of an earlier question about sorting arrays. I submitted that question before I discovered the source of the tabular output, which is unrelated to sorting.

---

As requested, here’s the expanded code: **Show-FileQueue** calls **Find-FilesWrittenSinceLastUpload**, which calls **Get-ChildItem**.

---

```
­$ATTRIBUTE_FILTER = "!D+!H+!S+!Temporary+!Encrypted"
$EXCLUSIONS = `
   "\.bak|\.bat|\.cab|\.cmd|\.com|\.db|\.dll|\.dmp|\.exe|\.ini|\.lnk|\.log|`
   ^max-.*js$|\.msi|\.sys|\.tmp|\.temp|template|test|- Copy|New-Folder|prototype|_vti"
$lastUploadTime = A string representation of a TimeSpan object; value is "15 Jun 2023 12:24"
…
function Show-FileQueue {
   param( [switch] [bool] $ignoreLastWriteTime = $false )
   [System.IO.FileInfo[]] $queue = $null
   if ($true -eq $ignoreLastWriteTime) {
      $queue = Find-FilesWrittenSinceLastUpload -ignoreLastWriteTime $true
   } else {             
      $queue = Find-FilesWrittenSinceLastUpload 
   }
   $fileCount = ($null -eq $queue ? 0 : [int]$queue.length)
   if ($fileCount -eq 0) {
      Write-Host "Found no new/changed files`n"
   } else {
      if ($false -eq $ignoreLastWriteTime) { 
         $queue | Sort-Object -property lastWriteTime | `
         Format-Table -property name, lastWriteTime, length
      }
      $totalBytes = 0
      foreach ($file in $queue) {
         $totalBytes += $file.length
      }
      $suffix = $fileCount -eq 1 ? "" : "s"
      Write-Host $("`n{0:n0} file$suffix, {1:n0} bytes`n" -f $fileCount, $totalBytes)
   }
return $queue
______________________________________________________________

function Find-FilesWrittenSinceLastUpload {
param ( [switch] [bool] $ignoreLastWriteTime = $false )
   $clientRoot = Get-ClientRootFolder
   Confirm-NotNullOrWhiteSpace -string $clientRoot -description $CLIENT_ROOT_DESCRIPTION
   Confirm-PathExists -path $clientRoot -description $CLIENT_ROOT_DESCRIPTION

   $lastUploadTime = Get-LastUploadTime
   $message = "`nLooking for files in $clientRoot & subfolders"
   if ($false -eq $ignoreLastWriteTime) {
      $message += (", created or changed since " + $lastUploadTime)
   }
   Write-Host $message
   Write-Debug "Excluding folders & files whose names match any of these regular expressions:`n"
      $EXCLUSIONS -split "\|" | ForEach-Object{ write-debug $_ }
   Write-Debug ""

   [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$queue = $null     # So queue object is visible at return statement
   $stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
   $stopwatch.start()
   if ($true -eq $ignoreLastWriteTime) {
      $queue = Get-ChildItem -path $clientRoot -recurse -attributes $ATTRIBUTE_FILTER | Where-Object `
      fullName -notmatch $EXCLUSIONS
   } else {
      $queue = Get-ChildItem -path $clientRoot -recurse -attributes $ATTRIBUTE_FILTER | Where-Object `
      -FilterScript {`
         ($_.fullName -notmatch $EXCLUSIONS) -and ($_.lastWriteTime -gt $lastUploadTime) `
      } 
   }
   $stopwatch.stop()
   $timespan    = New-TimeSpan -milliseconds $stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
   $elapsedTime = Convert-TimeSpanToString -timeSpan $timeSpan
   Write-Debug "File search completed in $elapsedTime"
   return $queue
}
```

Comment: your code is producing no output as the output is being assigned to `$queue` so its unclear what you mean

Comment: If you need to examine the output, why not just pipe it to `Out-Gridview`?

Comment: As commenters wrote, there shouldn't be any output from the code shown here (except for any error message). Do you accidentally (implicitly) output the variable `$queue` later in the code?

Comment: Yes, I return $queue from the function to the caller. The caller does some work, and then returns $queue to *its* caller, and that where if goes nuts. When I step over the caller's statement to return $queue (return to the caller's caller), that's when the tabular output appears.  FYI, the output contains columns labeled Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, and Name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To answer Scepticalist 2's question, I can't examine the output in its current form, because it's dozens of screens long, too much to easily read. That's why I iterate through the queue & create a summary.

Comment: Please insert full code you use for this - with variables included. (Guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You tried adding `out-null` to your `Get-childItem` call, but like you noticed, that stops your script from handling output. Wherever you're running the outermost command (e.g. at the command line) you can prevent all output with `Out-Null`, e.g. `Show-FileQueue | Out-Null`.

Comment: Interesting suggestion!  I changed the very last line of the code above to ``` return $queue | Out-Null`` , but it no effect. I may have not have stated it clearly, but the unwanted tabular output only appears when I execute that particular line.  It's almost as if the system is holding the output in a buffer, and for some reason decides that's the right time to send it to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stroniax suggested, I changed the last line of the code above (where the unwanted output began appearing) to:

```
return $queue | Out-Null
```

and **the unwanted tabular output was gone**! I understand what **Out-Null** does, but I don’t understand why that simple return statement triggered the undesired output. But at least I can put this problem to bed!

Thanks to all who took the time to look at this issue. If anyone knows what caused the weird behavior in the first place, I'd love to hear the explanation! I learn more about PowerShell every day!